# sequelize raw query in express app

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to call a simple sequelize raw query to get all the users in the users table but I am getting the error.

Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

what am I doing wrong here?

**models/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.json`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, config
  );
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**controllers/users**

```
const db  = require('../models/index').db;

module.exports = {

  getAllUsers(req, res){
    db.query('SELECT * FROM "Users" As Users', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(result => {
      return res.status(201).send({
        result
      });
    })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change

```
const db  = require('../models/index').db;
```

to

```
const db  = require('../models/index');
```

and add `const sequelize = require('sequelize');`